# Expectation of censored Normal distribution

Tags: random-variables, normal-distribution

Say $X \sim N \left( \mu, \sigma \right)$. Now I have another `random variable` $Y$ which is created by retaining all positive values of $X$ as original but all negative values of $X$ are censored at 0.

I am wondering if there is any analytical closed form formula to calculate the value of $E \left[  Y\right]$.

I searched over internet and stack exchange as well, but so far I am only able to find similar discussion on `Truncated` random variables not `censored` one.

Any pointer will be very helpful.

Comment: Am I right in saying that $Y = \max(0,X)$?

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391) + [please avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933). Instead of searching over internet, do some genuine mathematical effort.

Answer (score -1):

We are trying to find the expectation of $Y = \max(0,X)$. Conditional on the event $\{ X \leq 0 \}$ we have $Y=0$, whereas on the event $\{ X \geq 0 \}$, $Y$ has the distribution of a truncated $\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$ distribution on the interval $(0,\infty)$.

The truncated normal distribution has mean $\mu + \sigma \phi(\mu/\sigma)/\Phi(\mu/\sigma)$, where $\phi$ is the standard normal PDF, and the probability that $X > 0$ is $\Phi(\mu/\sigma)$, where
$$\Phi(x) = \int_{-\infty}^x \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-z^2/2} dz$$
is the standard normal CDF.
Hence by the law of total expectation,
$$\mathbb{E}[Y] = \Phi \left (\frac{\mu}{\sigma} \right )\left (\mu + \sigma \frac{\phi(\mu/\sigma)}{\Phi(\mu/\sigma)} \right).$$

Comment: Apologies. I have corrected some errors.